# What is the numeral for base greater than 16 in bc?

Tags: bc

I recently read about bc and found that it supports obase upto 999. Can anyone point me to the numeral set for bc for base greater than 16.

Comment: the decimals from 0 to ($base minus one)? `echo "obase=20; 20" | bc`, `echo "obase=20; 39" | bc`, `echo "obase=20; 40" | bc`

Comment: So, it is a space separated decimal numbers for each digit ?

Comment: It wouldn't have been particularly difficult for you to try this out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bc can process numbers with bases up to 999.

As an example:

```
$ echo "ibase=10;obase=40;3*40^2+7" | bc
03 00 07
```

Or, as it should be "307" `= 3*40^2 + 0*40^1 + 7*40^0`. Or 4807 in decimal.

```
$  echo "ibase=10;obase=10;3*40^2+7" | bc
4807
```

So, the values are printed as a two digit (decimal) number with an space as separator.
Some other example:

```
$ echo "ibase=10;obase=530;371*530^9+222*530^3+127" | bc
371 000 000 000 000 000 222 000 000 127
```

Or, maybe (in bash), the same number:

```
$ bc <<<"obase=530;1224212292558591376050694127"
371 000 000 000 000 000 222 000 000 127
```

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in the [manual page for `bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc):

> For bases greater than 16, bc uses a multi-character digit method of printing the numbers where each higher base digit is printed as a base 10 number. The multi-character digits are separated by spaces. Each digit contains the number of characters required to represent the base ten value of "obase-1".